# Spring 4 + Struts 2 + Hibernate 4 + Tiles 3 Can't creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]

Tags: spring, tile

I was create a project with Spring 4 + Struts 2 + Hibernate 4, It's run correct. But it has error when I add Tiles 3.

## Following is the exception info.

```
Type Exception Report

Message Unable to instantiate Action, loginActionBean, defined for 'login' in namespace '/'Error creating bean with name 'loginActionBean' defined in URL [file:/C:/Users/zhaogl/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/secondhandcar/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.action.LoginAction]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Root Cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.action.LoginAction.<init>(LoginAction.java:17)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:148)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1008)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:130)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:139)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:109)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:288)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:388)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:187)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:478)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

## Following is web.xml.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

## Following is tiles.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="layout" template="/WEB-INF/template/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/login.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="*" extends="layout">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/{1}.jsp" />
    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

## Following is applicationContext.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="tilesViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/classes/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/template/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean name="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/secondhandcar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8&amp;useSSL=false" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="sessionFactoryBase"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>com/org/cseeing/secondhandcar/pojo/user.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>com/org/cseeing/secondhandcar/pojo/car.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                hibernate.format_sql=true
                hibernate.show_sql=true
                hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="userdao" class="com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.dao.userDAO" />
    <bean name="userservice" class="com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.service.userService" />

    <bean name="cardao" class="com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.dao.carDAO" />
    <bean name="carservice" class="com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.service.carService" />

    <bean name="loginActionBean" class="com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.action.LoginAction"
        scope="prototype" />
    <bean name="indexActionBean" class="com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.action.IndexAction"
        scope="prototype" />
    <bean name="carsActionBean" class="com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.action.CarsAction"
        scope="prototype" />
    <bean name="authenticationInterceptorBean"
        class="com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.interceptor.AuthenticationInterceptor"
        scope="prototype" />
</beans>
```

## Following is pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.org.cseeing</groupId>
    <artifactId>secondhandcar</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>secondhandcar Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opensymphony</groupId>
            <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring end -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>secondhandcar</finalName>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <org.hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</org.hibernate.version>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I was try to move the tiles.xml to different path and change the definitions value in tilesConfigurer, But the error is still appear.

I have debug the code, 'servletContext' is null when initialize TilesConfigurer, I think it mat be missed some config in applicationContext.xml, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Did you look at the stacktrace  having  NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION  at `com.org.cseeing.secondhandcar.action.LoginAction.<init>(LoginAction.java:17)` ?

Comment: It's an init function. ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "applicationContext.xml" });